# How do I write standard error to a file while using "tee" with a pipe?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, tee

I know how to use `tee` to write the output ([standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)) of `aaa.sh` to `bbb.out`, while still displaying it in the terminal:

```
./aaa.sh | tee bbb.out
```

How would I now also write [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) to a file named `ccc.out`, while still having it displayed?

Comment: To clarify -- do you want stderr to go to the screen as well as the file?

Comment: I did, I will edit my post to clarify that.  I do believe lhunath's solution will suffice. Thanks for the help all!

Comment: `stderr` outputs to both the terminal and the file. May I ask if you want `stdout` outputs to the terminal, or to the file, or both? In my case, I need `stdout` only output to the file (as it is too verbose), while `stderr` outputs to both the terminal and the file. I got a solution already. I wonder if that will help on your question as well.

Answer (score 1048, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to still see standard error and standard output on the terminal.  You could go for [Josh Kelley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-standard-error-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe/692009#692009), but I find keeping a `tail` around in the background which outputs your log file very hackish and cludgy.  Notice how you need to keep an extra [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) and do cleanup afterward by killing it and technically should be doing that in a `trap '...' EXIT`.

There is a better way to do this, and you've already discovered it: `tee`.

Only, instead of just using it for your standard output, have a tee for standard output and one for standard error.  How will you accomplish this?  Process substitution and file redirection:

```
command > >(tee -a stdout.log) 2> >(tee -a stderr.log >&2)
```

Let's split it up and explain:

```
> >(..)
```

`>(...)` (process substitution) creates a FIFO and lets `tee` listen on it.  Then, it uses `>` (file redirection) to redirect the standard output of `command` to the FIFO that your first `tee` is listening on.

The same thing for the second:

```
2> >(tee -a stderr.log >&2)
```

We use process substitution again to make a `tee` process that reads from standard input and dumps it into `stderr.log`.  `tee` outputs its input back on standard output, but since its input is our standard error, we want to redirect `tee`'s standard output  to our standard error again.  Then we use file redirection to redirect `command`'s standard error to the FIFO's input (`tee`'s standard input).

See *[Input And Output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput)*

Process substitution is one of those really lovely things you get as a bonus of choosing Bash as your shell as opposed to `sh` (POSIX or Bourne).

---

In `sh`, you'd have to do things manually:

```
out="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/out.$$" err="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/err.$$"
mkfifo "$out" "$err"
trap 'rm "$out" "$err"' EXIT
tee -a stdout.log < "$out" &
tee -a stderr.log < "$err" >&2 &
command >"$out" 2>"$err"
```

Comment: I tried this: `$ echo "HANG" > >(tee stdout.log) 2> >(tee stderr.log >&2)` which works, but waits for input.  Is there a simple reason why this happens?

Comment: @Justin: I don't know what you mean by "waits for input".  The command you gave does not "wait" for anything with me.

Comment: @lhunath, I'm not using tcsh for programming, but thanks for the detaild review of its shortcomings.

Comment: I seem to be doing something wrong. I use `tee in | /bin/bash > >(tee out) 2> >(tee err >&2)`, but typing `echo test; exit` does show neither the command prompt, nor the exit. in and out are logged correctly, but err is neither echoed nor logged... any ideas maybe?

Comment: @SillyFreak I don't understand what you want to do or what the problem is you're having.  echo test; exit doesn't produce any output on stdout, so err will remain empty.

Comment: thanks for that comment; I figured out what my logical error was afterwards: when invoked as an interactive shell, bash prints a command prompt and echoes exit to stderr. However, if stderr is redirected, bash starts as noninteractive by default; compare `/bin/bash 2> err` and `/bin/bash -i 2> err`

Comment: And for those who "seeing is believing", a quick test: `(echo "Test Out";>&2 echo "Test Err") > >(tee stdout.log) 2> >(tee stderr.log >&2)`

Comment: Looks like bash stole the "Pipeline Branching" feature from `rc`, the Plan 9 shell.

Comment: For those who are forced to execute a script in a classic `sh` shell for some reason, you can run `bash` inline like this:

`bash -c 'command > >(tee -a stdout.log) 2> >(tee -a stderr.log >&2)'`

Comment: Can this be used to write both to the same file, but in a synchronized way, so the order of stderr and stdout messages is preserved, while each stream of the supbrocess is still directed to the corresponding stream of the calling process? I don't know, but I can imagine if tee does some buffering, the subprocess may finish writing something to stdout and write to stderr, but the second tee receiving the stderr message may finish writing it to the file earlier than the first.

Comment: @Larry I'm running into this right now myself. I tried using the same file name in the above command, and a combination of stdout and stderr are not going in the same order. I was hoping to use something like `command 1>logfile 2> >(tee -a &1 >&2)` so stderr points to the same stream as 1 (with 1 going only to a file and not console, in my case), but that didn't work either. I guess we have to pick between different files or slightly buffered output

Comment: Since this process substitution seems different than a pipe, does it mean that we still have the correct exit status of the original command?  In other words, would this work as expected? `my_cmd > >(tee -a x.log) 2> >(tee -a y.log >&2); rv=$?; echo "my_cmd exit status = $rv"`

Comment: What does >&2 at the end of the command in this answer do?  Why isn't it just `... 2> >(tee -a stderr.log)`

Comment: this reorders the output and is useless; why would I be using `tee` at all if I wanted that?

Comment: @PranavRai since `2>` handles output that came from stderr, you probably want to keep `tee`'s version of those bytes to stay on stderr. `tee` normally outputs on `stdout`, so >&2 makes sure that your error output goes back to stderr after tee is done with it.

Comment: Hi! Just a clarification. Why do we need to >&2 at the end? Is there a problem presenting the error messages in the terminal through the second tee's stdout (omitting >&2) instead of sending it to its stderr?

Comment: @Sotiris because errors are expected to arrive on FD 2, not FD 1, and if you omit `>&2` you'll end up with output intended for stderr on stdout. For a regular terminal, this is usually not noticeable since both are attached to the same display; but keeping errors separate from standard output is valuable in many cases such as if you want to silence errors (at a higher level) or colorize them.

Comment: Oh I see @Ihunath! It is out of respect for this convention. Thank you very much and really great and elegant solution, if I may say so! :)

Comment: This also works in ash.

Answer (score 989):

Simply:

```
./aaa.sh 2>&1 | tee -a log
```

This simply redirects standard error to standard output, so tee echoes both to *log* and to the screen.  Maybe I'm missing something, because some of the other solutions seem really complicated.

**Note:** Since Bash version 4 you may use `|&` as an abbreviation for `2>&1 |`:

```
./aaa.sh |& tee -a log
```

Comment: That works fine if you want both stdout (channel 1) and stderr (channel 2) logged to the same file (a single file containing the mixture of both stdout and sterr). The other, more complicated solution allows you to separate stdout and stderr into 2 different files (stdout.log and stderr.log, respectively). Sometimes that is important, sometimes it's not.

Comment: The other solutions are far more complicated than necessary in many cases.  This one works perfectly for me.

Comment: The problem with this method is that you lose the exit/status code from the aaa.sh process, which can be important (e.g. when using in a makefile). You don't have this problem with the accepted answer.

Comment: if you don't mind merged stdout/stderr then `./aaa.sh |& tee aaa.log` works (in bash).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '&'`

Comment: @Heartinpiece: there must be no space between `|` and `&`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian `./Bulldozer.py |& test` Still doesn't work  
`GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)`

Comment: @Heartinpiece: 3.2 is from 2007. [The man page from 2009 has this feature](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Comment: `|&` was officially added in 4 as a "synonym" for `2>&1 |` (http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/bash4)

Comment: @Stefaan I believe you can retain exit status if you prepend the command chain with `set -o pipefail` followed by `;` or `&&` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: If you wanna log only errors: ./aaa.sh 2>&1>/dev/null | tee -a errors.log

Comment: This is only for interactive usage, because in a script, I want to have the each stream of the subprocess to be duplicated strictly to the corresponding stream of the parent, in one thousand out of three cases.

Comment: This is indeed much simpler than the chosen answer, sufficient in most cases and much easier to remember; still, the chosen answer has the added benefits of allowing the separation of stdin and stdout and of teaching something new and interesting, and is not more complicated than a copy-and-paste.

Comment: @Stefaan - That issue can be solved using the array variable PIPESTATUS. In your example, the exit status would be in $PIPESTATUS[0].

Answer (score 88):

This may be useful for people finding this via Google.  Simply uncomment the example you want to try out.  Of course, feel free to rename the output files.

```
#!/bin/bash

STATUSFILE=x.out
LOGFILE=x.log

### All output to screen
### Do nothing, this is the default


### All Output to one file, nothing to the screen
#exec > ${LOGFILE} 2>&1


### All output to one file and all output to the screen
#exec > >(tee ${LOGFILE}) 2>&1


### All output to one file, STDOUT to the screen
#exec > >(tee -a ${LOGFILE}) 2> >(tee -a ${LOGFILE} >/dev/null)


### All output to one file, STDERR to the screen
### Note you need both of these lines for this to work
#exec 3>&1
#exec > >(tee -a ${LOGFILE} >/dev/null) 2> >(tee -a ${LOGFILE} >&3)


### STDOUT to STATUSFILE, stderr to LOGFILE, nothing to the screen
#exec > ${STATUSFILE} 2>${LOGFILE}


### STDOUT to STATUSFILE, stderr to LOGFILE and all output to the screen
#exec > >(tee ${STATUSFILE}) 2> >(tee ${LOGFILE} >&2)


### STDOUT to STATUSFILE and screen, STDERR to LOGFILE
#exec > >(tee ${STATUSFILE}) 2>${LOGFILE}


### STDOUT to STATUSFILE, STDERR to LOGFILE and screen
#exec > ${STATUSFILE} 2> >(tee ${LOGFILE} >&2)


echo "This is a test"
ls -l sdgshgswogswghthb_this_file_will_not_exist_so_we_get_output_to_stderr_aronkjegralhfaff
ls -l ${0}
```

Comment: No, and I guess exec can use some explaining. `exec >` means, move the target of a file descriptor to a certain destination. The default is 1, so, `exec > /dev/null` moves the output of stdout to /dev/null from now on in this session. The current file descriptors for this session can be seen by doing `ls -l /dev/fd/`. Try it! Then see what happens when you issue `exec 2>/tmp/stderr.log.` Additionally, `exec 3>&1` means, create a new file descriptor with number 3, and redirect it to the target of file descriptor 1. In the example, the target was the screen when the command was issued.

Comment: The example to show stdout and stderr both in screen and separate files is awesome!!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The "All output to one file, STDERR to the screen" part can be put on one line (just put `3>&1` at the front):

`exec 3>&1 > >(tee -a ${LOGFILE} >/dev/null) 2> >(tee -a ${LOGFILE} >&3)`

Note if you want stderr to print to screen as 2 still, just switch to

`3>&2` instead of `3>&1`

Comment: You also don't need the `tee` command if you're not wanting the output on screen. Instead of using tee with /dev/null, you can just output to the file:

just do `exec 3>&2 1>${LOGFILE} 2> >(tee -a ${LOGFILE} >&3)`

Answer (score 25):

To redirect standard error to a file, display standard output to the screen, and also save standard output to a file:

```
./aaa.sh 2>ccc.out | tee ./bbb.out
```

To display both standard error and standard output to screen and also save both to a file, you can use Bash's [I/O redirection](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Create a new file descriptor 4, pointed at the file
# which will receive standard error.
exec 4<>ccc.out

# Also print the contents of this file to screen.
tail -f ccc.out &

# Run the command; tee standard output as normal, and send standard error
# to our file descriptor 4.
./aaa.sh 2>&4 | tee bbb.out

# Clean up: Close file descriptor 4 and kill tail -f.
exec 4>&-
kill %1
```

Comment: I expect that the user wants stderr to go to their console in addition to the file, though such wasn't explicitly specified.

Comment: I should have been clearer, I did want stderr to the screen too.  I still enjoyed Josh Kelley's solution but find lhunath's to suit my needs more. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 24):

In other words, you want to pipe stdout into one filter (`tee bbb.out`) and stderr into another filter (`tee ccc.out`). There is no standard way to pipe anything other than stdout into another command, but you can work around that by juggling file descriptors.

```
{ { ./aaa.sh | tee bbb.out; } 2>&1 1>&3 | tee ccc.out; } 3>&1 1>&2
```

See also [How to grep standard error stream (stderr)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-to-grep-standard-error-stream-stderr) and [When would you use an additional file descriptor?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18899/when-would-you-use-an-additional-file-descriptor)

In bash (and ksh and zsh), but not in other POSIX shells such as dash, you can use [process substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe/692407#692407):

```
./aaa.sh > >(tee bbb.out) 2> >(tee ccc.out)
```

Beware that in bash, this command returns as soon as `./aaa.sh` finishes, even if the `tee` commands are still executed (ksh and zsh do wait for the subprocesses). This may be a problem if you do something like `./aaa.sh > >(tee bbb.out) 2> >(tee ccc.out); process_logs bbb.out ccc.out`. In that case, use file descriptor juggling or ksh/zsh instead.

Comment: This seems like the only answer that allows keeping the stdout/stderr streams as-is (eg. not merging them). Sweet!

Comment: The simplest approach for `sh`, useful for cron jobs, where process substitution is not available.

Answer (score 17):

If using Bash:

```
# Redirect standard out and standard error separately
% cmd >stdout-redirect 2>stderr-redirect

# Redirect standard error and out together
% cmd >stdout-redirect 2>&1

# Merge standard error with standard out and pipe
% cmd 2>&1 |cmd2
```

Credit (not answering from the top of my head) goes here: *[Re: bash : stderr & more (pipe for stderr)](http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2003-06/msg00772.html)*

Comment: The question was "How would I now also write standard error to a file named ccc.out, while still having it displayed?"

Answer (score 13):

If you're using [Z shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) (`zsh`), you can use multiple redirections, so you don't even need `tee`:

```
./cmd 1>&1 2>&2 1>out_file 2>err_file
```

Here you're simply redirecting each stream to itself *and* the target file.

---

**Full example**

```
% (echo "out"; echo "err">/dev/stderr) 1>&1 2>&2 1>/tmp/out_file 2>/tmp/err_file
out
err
% cat /tmp/out_file
out
% cat /tmp/err_file
err
```

Note that this requires the `MULTIOS` option to be set (which is the default).

> `MULTIOS`
>
> Perform implicit `tee`s or `cat`s when multiple redirections are attempted (see [Redirection](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios)).

Comment: In contrast to [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), presumably(?). What other shells can do it as well? [Fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fish_(Unix_shell))?

Comment: This reorders the output and so is useless

Answer (score 10):

Like the [accepted answer well explained by lhunath](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692407/6862843), you can use

```
command > >(tee -a stdout.log) 2> >(tee -a stderr.log >&2)
```

**Beware than if you use bash you could have some issue**.

Let me take the [matthew-wilcoxson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266375/matthew-wilcoxson) example.

> And for those who "seeing is believing", a quick test:
>
> ```
> (echo "Test Out";>&2 echo "Test Err") > >(tee stdout.log) 2> >(tee stderr.log >&2)
> ```

Personally, when I try, I have this result:

```
user@computer:~$ (echo "Test Out";>&2 echo "Test Err") > >(tee stdout.log) 2> >(tee stderr.log >&2)
user@computer:~$ Test Out
Test Err
```

Both messages do not appear at the same level. Why does `Test Out` seem to be put like if it is my previous command?

The prompt is on a blank line letting me think the process is not finished, and when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> this fix it.
When I check the content of the files, it is ok, and redirection works.

Let’s take another test.

```
function outerr() {
  echo "out"     # stdout
  echo >&2 "err" # stderr
}
```

```
user@computer:~$ outerr
out
err

user@computer:~$ outerr >/dev/null
err

user@computer:~$ outerr 2>/dev/null
out
```

Trying again the redirection, but with this function:

```
function test_redirect() {
  fout="stdout.log"
  ferr="stderr.log"
  echo "$ outerr"
  (outerr) > >(tee "$fout") 2> >(tee "$ferr" >&2)
  echo "# $fout content: "
  cat "$fout"
  echo "# $ferr content: "
  cat "$ferr"
}
```

Personally, I have this result:

```
user@computer:~$ test_redirect
$ outerr
# stdout.log content:
out
out
err
# stderr.log content:
err
user@computer:~$
```

No prompt on a blank line, but I don't see normal output. The *stdout.log* content seem to be wrong, and only stderr.log seem to be ok.

If I relaunch it, the output can be different...

So, why?

Because, [like explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14737103/6862843):

> Beware that in bash, this command returns as soon as [first command] finishes, even if the tee commands are still executed (ksh and zsh do wait for the subprocesses)

So, if you use Bash, prefer use the better example given in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14737103/6862843):

```
{ { outerr | tee "$fout"; } 2>&1 1>&3 | tee "$ferr"; } 3>&1 1>&2
```

It will fix the previous issues.

Now, the question is, how to retrieve exit status code?

`$?` does not work.

I have no found better solution than switch on pipefail with `set -o pipefail` (`set +o pipefail` to switch off) and use `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` like this:

```
function outerr() {
  echo "out"
  echo >&2 "err"
  return 11
}

function test_outerr() {
  local - # To preserve set option
  ! [[ -o pipefail ]] && set -o pipefail; # Or use second part directly
  local fout="stdout.log"
  local ferr="stderr.log"
  echo "$ outerr"
  { { outerr | tee "$fout"; } 2>&1 1>&3 | tee "$ferr"; } 3>&1 1>&2
  # First save the status or it will be lost
  local status="${PIPESTATUS[0]}" # Save first, the second is 0, perhaps tee status code.
  echo "==="
  echo "# $fout content :"
  echo "<==="
  cat "$fout"
  echo "===>"
  echo "# $ferr content :"
  echo "<==="
  cat "$ferr"
  echo "===>"
  if (( status > 0 )); then
    echo "Fail $status > 0"
    return "$status" # or whatever
  fi
}
```

```
user@computer:~$ test_outerr
$ outerr
err
out
===
# stdout.log content:
<===
out
===>
# stderr.log content:
<===
err
===>
Fail 11 > 0
```

Answer (score 7):

The following will work for KornShell (ksh) where the process substitution is not available,

```
# create a combined (standard input and standard output) collector
exec 3 <> combined.log

# stream standard error instead of standard output to tee, while draining all standard output to the collector
./aaa.sh 2>&1 1>&3 | tee -a stderr.log 1>&3

# cleanup collector
exec 3>&-
```

The real trick here, is the sequence of the `2>&1 1>&3` which in our case redirects the standard error to standard output and redirects the standard output to [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) 3. At this point the standard error and standard output are not combined yet.

In effect, the standard error (as standard input) is passed to `tee` where it logs to `stderr.log` and also redirects to file descriptor 3.

And file descriptor 3 is logging it to `combined.log` all the time. So the `combined.log` contains both standard output and standard error.

Comment: Nifty! Pity that's underrated because it's a nice option. I do have KSH, btw :)

Comment: Is file descriptor 3 special in some way? Or is it just any number higher than 2?

Comment: @PeterMortensen The point is to use an unused file descriptor.  `0` is `STDIN`.  `1` is `STDOUT`.  `2` is `STDERR`.  The next one is `3`.

Comment: @PeterMortensen I read somewhere that it can go up to 9.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, a script was running command while redirecting both stdout and stderr to a file, something like:

```
cmd > log 2>&1
```

I needed to update it such that when there is a failure, take some actions based on the error messages. I could of course remove the dup `2>&1` and capture the stderr from the script, but then the error messages won't go into the log file for reference. While the accepted [answer from lhunath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-standard-error-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe/692407#692407) is supposed to do the same, it redirects `stdout` and `stderr` to different files, which is not what I want, but it helped me to come up with the exact solution that I need:

```
(cmd 2> >(tee /dev/stderr)) > log
```

With the above, log will have a copy of both `stdout` and `stderr` and I can capture `stderr` from my script without having to worry about `stdout`.

Comment: This reorders the output

Comment: @jberryman Good point! I am not sure how to completely avoid it, though disabling buffering on stdout could help.

Comment: This seems to use an unnecessary subshell process.

Comment: Also, if you `tee` to `/dev/stderr`, I think there's a truncate on `/dev/stderr` before the data is sent.  It might be a better idea to `tee -a /dev/stderr`.

Comment: Finally, I'm pretty sure OP wanted to send the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to two different files.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [lhunath for the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-standard-error-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe/692407#692407) in POSIX.

Here's a more complex situation I needed in POSIX with the proper fix:

```
# Start script main() function
# - We redirect standard output to file_out AND terminal
# - We redirect standard error to file_err, file_out AND terminal
# - Terminal and file_out have both standard output and standard error, while file_err only holds standard error

main() {
    # my main function
}

log_path="/my_temp_dir"
pfout_fifo="${log_path:-/tmp}/pfout_fifo.$$"
pferr_fifo="${log_path:-/tmp}/pferr_fifo.$$"

mkfifo "$pfout_fifo" "$pferr_fifo"
trap 'rm "$pfout_fifo" "$pferr_fifo"' EXIT

tee -a "file_out" < "$pfout_fifo" &
    tee -a "file_err" < "$pferr_fifo" >>"$pfout_fifo" &
    main "$@" >"$pfout_fifo" 2>"$pferr_fifo"; exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Compilation errors which are sent to standard error (`STDERR`) can be redirected or save to a file by:

Bash:

```
gcc temp.c &> error.log
```

[C shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell) (`csh`):

```
% gcc temp.c |& tee error.log
```

See: *[How can I redirect compilation/build error to a file?](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/how-to-redirect-compilation-build-error-to-a-file-831099/)*

Comment: The OP was asking for the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` to be sent to two different places.  This merges them.