# Django tests dump data/ results

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, text-files

When I run django tests through `manage.py test` is there a way to output the result to a text file?

Comment: What's wrong with `manage.py test > results.txt`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

on linux, you can do this:

```
python manage.py test > stdout.txt 2> stderr.txt
```

to redirect the output to files.

Answer (score 3):

Linux only...

```
python manage.py test 2>&1 | tee -a test.txt
```

This captures the `stdout` and `stderr` results as a single stream and still sends the output to the console.

Also see [In the shell, what does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean) for the output redirection explanation

And [How do I write stderr to a file while using "tee" with a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe) for a slightly different output redirection method

Comment: Do you know why `python manage.py test 2>&1 | tee test.txt` doesn't work in macOS? I was trying to debug why it resulted in an empty file.  I was seeing the console output, but the file, which previously had data, ended up being 0 bytes. And in either case (merging versus not merging stdout/err), the date modified of the file never changes. Without merging, this was actually working in Django 3.2, and the date modified was updated, but in Django 4.2, no lmd update... Confounding.