# 'tee' in makefile, can we copy stderr as well?

Tags: shell, makefile, tee

I hope to record the result of stderr & stdout to different files, while watching both outputs from the terminal.

So I use `tee`, and found a solution in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692407/1731877).

But the sad thing is, it can't work when put into a makefile:

```
all:
    @command > >(tee stdout.log) 2> >(tee stderr.log >&2)
```

It seems that `make` will use `sh -c` to execute this line, which doesn't understand well about the syntax.

Can we have another solution for this?

Comment: `tee` works; it's the process substitution that the shell used by `make` doesn't understand.

Comment: a workaround is to set the variable `SHELL` in make to `/bin/bash` using `make SHELL=/bin/bash`, or putting `SHELL:=/bin/bash` at the start of the `Makefile`.

Comment: Thanks @Petesh, can you post the answer so I can mark this as solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use this syntax in your `Makefile` you need to change the shell that make uses for running commands by setting the `SHELL` variable.

By invoking make using: `make SHELL=/bin/bash`, or putting `SHELL:=/bin/bash` at the start of the `Makefile` it should accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

A brute-force way would be to not tee in the makefile but instead tail -f one of the files in the background:

```
$ tail -f stderr.log & tail -f stdout.log
[... ^C]
$ kill $!
```