# Writing to stderr using /dev/tty?

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, tty

I want to write to only stderr using /dev/tty . If I write directly to /dev/tty (with tee), it seems like that will print out on stdout. Is that correct? How can I specify that I want to print to stderr?

Currently the line in bash looks like

```
echo "foo" >&2 | tee /dev/tty | logger -it "my_script"
```

Comment: You have a command that produces output on stdout and stderr, and you want to log stderr and also show it on screen?

Comment: Perhaps what you really want is `echo "foo" | tee /dev/stderr | logger -it "my_script"`

Comment: You might find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/692407/1608708

Comment: @anishsane Didn't see your comment, if you want to post it as an answer I'll delete mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we split apart your command apart with the result of each command after the #

```
echo "foo" >&2 # echo "foo" and redirect to fd 2 (/dev/sdterr)
| #pipe stdout to  
tee /dev/tty #both send stdout to file /dev/tty, which is terminal file that can output both stdout and stderr depending on what you pass to it (so you probably want /dev/stdout/ or /dev/stderr directly instead) and pass it along to the next pipe
| #pipe stdout to
logger -it "my_script"
```

So it depends on what you want to do (In the above foo gets redirected to stderr and nothing gets piped to `tee`)

If you want to print foo to stderr and pass stdout to your script you can just do

```
echo "foo" | tee /dev/stderr | yourscirpt
```

Then `tee` will print to stderr and foo will get piped as stdout to yourscript.

Comment: You grokked my intent exactly - printing to current stderr and then piping it along elsewhere.