# How to keep stderr output and also redirect it to file

Tags: linux, bash

I tried 
`ffmpeg -i  rtsp://172.19.1.34/live.sdp -acodec copy -vcodec copy b.mp4 2>>log.txt 2>&1`

to  keep stderr output and also redirect it to file.

But it failed.

However, I can keep the stderr output by

`ffmpeg -i  rtsp://172.19.1.34/live.sdp -acodec copy -vcodec copy b.mp4 2>log.txt`

Comment: [`cmd args |& tee file`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tee). See [How do I write stderr to a file while using “tee” with a pipe?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/692407/4279) if you don't want to merge stdout/stderr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redirect stderr to stdout with `2>&1`, and then use `tee` command.

> cmd 2>&1 | tee -a log

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ffmpeg -i  rtsp://172.19.1.34/live.sdp -acodec copy -vcodec copy b.mp4 &> log.txt
```

or this

```
nohup ffmpeg -i  rtsp://172.19.1.34/live.sdp -acodec copy -vcodec copy b.mp4
```

and look for `nohup.out` after the command returns.