# How do I copy stderr without stopping it writing to the terminal?

Tags: bash, stderr

I want to write a shell script that runs a command, writing its stderr to my terminal as it arrives. However, I also want to save stderr to a variable, so I can inspect it later.

How can I achieve this? Should I use `tee`, or a subshell, or something else?

I've tried this:

```
# Create FD 3 that can be used so stdout still comes through 
exec 3>&1

# Run the command, piping stdout to normal stdout, but saving stderr.
{ ERROR=$( $@ 2>&1 1>&3) ; }

echo "copy of stderr: $ERROR"
```

However, this doesn't write stderr to the console, it only saves it.

I've also tried:

```
{ $@; } 2> >(tee stderr.txt >&2 )

echo "stderr was:"
cat stderr.txt
```

However, I don't want the temporary file.

Comment: `tee /dev/tty` might be what you want.

Comment: redirect stderr? `2>err.txt`

Comment: @EtanReisner ooh, that very nearly works. However, it seems to be discarding newlines.

Comment: Discarding newlines where?

Comment: @WilfredHughes, "discarding newlines" sounds like you're typing `echo $ERROR` instead of `echo "$ERROR"`

Comment: There is a highly upvoted answer to a similar question which thoroughly answers this.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/692407/208257

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credit goes to @Etan Reisner for the fundamentals of the approach; however, it's better to **use `tee` with `/dev/stderr`** rather than `/dev/tty` in order to preserve normal behavior (if you send to `/dev/tty`, the outside world doesn't see it as stderr output, and can neither capture nor suppress it):

Here's the full idiom:

```
exec 3>&1   # Save original stdout in temp. fd #3.
# Redirect stderr to *captured* stdout, send stdout to *saved* stdout, also send
# captured stdout (and thus stderr) to original stderr.
errOutput=$("$@" 2>&1 1>&3 | tee /dev/stderr)
exec 3>&-   # Close temp. fd.

echo "copy of stderr: $errOutput"
```

Answer (score 10):

I often want to do this, and find myself reaching for `/dev/stderr`, but there can be problems with this approach; for example, [Nix](https://nixos.org/nix) build scripts give "permission denied" errors if they try to write to `/dev/stdout` or `/dev/stderr`.

After reinventing this wheel a few times, my current approach is to use process substitution as follows:

```
myCmd 2> >(tee >(cat 1>&2))
```

Reading this from the outside in:

This will run `myCmd`, leaving its stdout as-is. The `2>` will redirect the stderr of `myCmd` to a different destination; the destination here is `>(tee >(cat 1>&2))` which will cause it to be piped into the command `tee >(cat 1>&2)`.

The `tee` command duplicates its input (in this case, the stderr of `myCmd`) to its stdout and to the given destination. The destination here is `>(cat 1>&2)`, which will cause the data to be piped into the command `cat 1>&2`.

The `cat` command just passes its input straight to stdout. The `1>&2` redirects stdout to go to stderr.

Reading from the inside out:

The `cat 1>&2` command redirects its stdin to stderr, so `>(cat 1>&2)` acts like `/dev/stderr`.

Hence `tee >(cat 1>&2)` duplicates its stdin to both stdout and stderr, acting like `tee /dev/stderr`.

We use `2> >(tee >(cat 1>&2))` to get 2 copies of stderr: one on stdout and one on stderr.

We can use the copy on stdout as normal, for example storing it in a variable. We can leave the copy on stderr to get printed to the terminal.

We can combine this with other redirections if we like, e.g.

```
# Create FD 3 that can be used so stdout still comes through 
exec 3>&1

# Run the command, redirecting its stdout to the shell's stdout,
# duplicating its stderr and sending one copy to the shell's stderr
# and using the other to replace the command's stdout, which we then
# capture
{ ERROR=$( $@ 2> >(tee >(cat 1>&2)) 1>&3) ; }

echo "copy of stderr: $ERROR"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following uses the idea of @Warbo and is shorter

```
command 2> >(tee /dev/stderr)
```