# Redirecting program output

Tags: linux, bash, unix

How do I redirect my program, so that the output goes to 3 file such that

1. stdout goes to file1
2. stderr goes to file2
3. the combined result of stdout and stderr goes to file3 in their original order
4. While redirecting, the output is also printed to the screen as the program is running

I tried

```
myprogram > file1 2> file2
```

but this does not satisfy 3 & 4.

Edit: It would be better if the screen displays messages immediately after they are printed. (to increase responsiveness)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write stderr to a file while using "tee" with a pipe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(./foo.sh > >(tee out.log) 2> >(tee err.log >&2)) |& tee all.log
```

What have we done here?  First, we create two subshells to run `tee out.log` and `tee err.log`, and redirect the appropriate descriptors to them.  We are careful to redirect `stdout` from `err.log` back to `stderr` where it belongs, otherwise it will mess up `out.log` (credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/692407/4323 for this idea).  Second, we put that entire thing in a subshell so that we can redirect its `stdout` and `stderr` in one shot to `all.log`, again using `tee` to print to the screen at the same time.

One caveat is that the program we're running is likely to buffer stdout when it is not a TTY/PTY (terminal device).  If you need immediate output from `stdout` on your screen and in the files, you can try running your program with [`unbuffer`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer), a utility which avoids this buffering.

Answer (score 0):

`myprogram > file1 2> file2 &> file3; cat file3`

Or do you think the `cat file3` is cheating?

Comment: Well it doesn't work on Linux which the OP is asking about.  Strange.  I have Bash 4.1.5, you probably have an older one.

Comment: I have version `3.2.53`.

Comment: Yeah, Mac OS is stuck on a very old Bash.