# ksh on BSD style UNIX. How to redirect stderr to tee and a file

Tags: shell, unix, redirect, stdout, stderr

A similar  question as been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe)

But it wont work for me

```
"shell.ksh"  > >(tee here.log ) 2> >(tee err.log)
ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error: `>' is not expected.
```

this command will not redirect stderr just stdop

```
"shell.ksh" | tee file.log 2>&1
```

I am on AIX running  some UNIX similar to BSD that does not have GNU extensions
and this is ksh

```
ps $$
      PID    TTY STAT  TIME COMMAND
 40632390  pts/6 A     0:00 -ksh
```

Any short and sweet solns folks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a wrapper script that should do what you want.  I can't confirm that it works on AIX ksh, but it works using `sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01` (Debian's `ksh` package calls it the "Real, AT&T version of the Korn shell."  This is intentionally neither [`pdksh`](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/pdksh/) nor its [`mksh`](https://www.mirbsd.org/mksh.htm) fork).

This is portable and should work in all POSIX shells.

### pipe1+2.ksh

```sh
#!/bin/ksh

touch err.log here.log      # create the logs now so tail -f doesn't complain
tail -f here.log &          # follow the output we'll pipe to later (run in bg)
HERE=$!                     # save the process ID of this backgrounded process
tail -f err.log >&2 &       # follow output (as above), pipe output to stderr
ERR=$!                      # save the process ID

"$@" > here.log 2> err.log  # run given command and pipe stdout and stderr
RET=$?                      # save return value

sleep 1                     # tail polls at 1/s, so wait one second

kill $HERE $ERR             # stop following those logs

exit $RET                   # restore the exit code from given command
```

So you invoke it as `pipe1+2.ksh shell.ksh` (assuming both commands are in your path).

Here's a test version of shell.ksh:

```sh
#!/bin/ksh

echo this output is stdout 1
echo this output is stderr >&2
echo this output is stdout 2
```

and a trial run:

```sh
# ksh pipe1+2.ksh ksh shell.ksh
this output is stdout 1
this output is stdout 2
this output is stderr
# cat here.log
this output is stdout 1
this output is stdout 2
# cat err.log
this output is stderr
```

A note:  because `tail -f` isn't instantaneous, stdout vs stderr will be slightly out of order.  It won't even be consistent between runs, at least with code that runs as fast as `echo`.

I doubt your version of `tail` supports it, but GNU tail has a `-s SECONDS` flag that lets you specify a different polling interval as a decimal value, so you can try e.g. `tail -f -s 0.01 …` to improve the ordering of what is displayed.  If your version of `sleep` also supports decimal values, change it to match that number.

<sub>(I had originally crafted a complicated file descriptor piping response based on one of the "more elaborate combinations" in the amazing [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/), but that didn't seem to work.  See the comments and/or the [initial version of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35541846/revisions#spacer-473db3eb-69b2-4065-9475-c38c54632fdd).)</sub>

Comment: Hey Adam !  Thanks for your response.  I ran it ditto like above on the command line. It did nothing on the screen no o/p `exec 3>&1; "test.sh" 2>&1 1>&3 3>&- |tee err.log 1>&2 3>&- |tee here.log` and it did not write to log either  `0 Feb 22 01:09 here.log       0 Feb 22 01:09 err.log`

Comment: Okay.  I was worried about that.  `tee` seems to play oddly with that logic even in other shells.  Not much consistency there.  I've therefore rewritten the whole thing with a wrapper script.

Comment: TY SM. Works as expected for above.