# List "svn up" errors when project won't update

Tags: bash, svn

I wrote a simple bash script to update all my 11 projects with Subversion 1.8.15 (under Debian 7).
Here's a part of it:

```
    echo "PHP PROJECT1 update..."
    cd $PHPDIR/Project1 && svn up

    echo "PHP PROJECT2 update..."
    cd $PHPDIR/Project2 && svn up

    ...
```

It works fine BUT...when error occures e.g svn can't update one project due to denied acces to folder or connection error, it skips updating this particular project and happily goes to the next project.

In this case,svn console output is long and it's hard to find those error messages,so I do not really know if ALL my Projects were updated.

My question is: does Subversion 1.8.15 stores logs from unsucessful updates and where I can find them?

EDIT:

Solution turns out to be way more interesting than I initially thought. My intention was to print stdOut and stdErr to console and ALSO print ONLY stdErr to /tmp/svnErr.log .
After a bit od searching i found this question [How do I write stderr to a file while using "tee" with a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe/692407#692407)

Thanks to this I learned about Process Substitution in bash.

Finally, my solution is:

`svn up > >(tee) 2> >(tee -a /tmp/svnErr.log >&2)`

Comment: SVN does not store any such log; all of its output is sent to the console.  Why not just redirect the output of each command to a file?

Comment: hmmm,I could...and then grep this output file for words like "error","problem" etc. Thanks for suggestion :)