# Msys: how to keep STDERR on the screen and at the same time copy both STDOUT and STDERR to files

Tags: sh, msys

I would like to be able to

- Display STDERR on the screen
- Copy STDOUT and STDERR in files (and if possible in the same file)

For information, I am using **Msys** to do that.

.

After doing some research on the SO, I have tried to use something like

`<my command> > >(tee stdout.log) 2> >(tee stderr.log)`

Bu I got the following error:

> sh: syntax error near unexpected token `>'

.

Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be no direct solution in Msys but the `>(tee ... )` solution works fine in *Nix, OSX, and probably Cygwin.

The workaround is to grep all the errors and warnings we want to keep them on the screen.

I have successfully used the following command for a makefile to compile C code:

`make 2>&1 | tee make.log | grep -E "(([Ee]rror|warning|make):|In function|undefined)"`

Comment: That is a good workaround. Could you, instead of using `grep -E` to get STDERR, use `grep -v` to exclude STDOUT and get everything else? Well, that assumes you know what the STDOUT is, which may not be the case.

Comment: @ViniciusPlacco: provided you know what would be in STDOUT, you can definitely use `grep -v` ... point is, a pattern on errors and warnings is much easier :)

Comment: Fair enough :) Good to have both in  the pocket. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple script (`test.sh`) that generates STDOUT and STDERR:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo hello
rm something 
exit
```

Then, to do what you want execute with the following:

```
./test.sh > stdout.log 2> >(tee stderr.log >&2)
```

You'll get the STDERR on the screen, and two separated log files with STDERR and STDOUT. I used part of the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe)

*Note that I am assuming you don't have a file called `something` on the current directory :)*

If you want both STDOUT and STDERR to go to the same file, use the `-a` option on `tee`:

```
./test.sh > std.log 2> >(tee -a std.log >&2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer although it might not work on MSys but just on Cygwin or shell. Where are you running this shell conmand?

Comment: I ran this on a MAC OS terminal in `bash`. I am not sure about running on MSYS.

Comment: ... unfortunately not working in Msys, as I mentioned. Probably works in Cygwin though.