# nohup - Not printing all logs

Tags: linux, unix, nohup

I am running two scripts

```
# Script 1
nohup sh {command} &
```

and the nohup.out is having all logs in details  (for script 1)

```
# Script 2 
nohup sh {command} > {log_path} 2>&1 &
```

But nohup.out having only limited log as listed below (for script 2),

```
## Script2 output
   Shutdown message has been posted to the server.
   Server shutdown may take a while - check logfiles for completion
```

How can i generate all logs by using script 2 format in nohup.out itself .

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I usually ask my shell/nohup questions at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Looks like script 2 errors are overriding. Try removing error redirection and check.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have both files (nohup.out and {log_path}) you can try:

```
((nohup {command}) > >(tee {log_path}) 2> >(tee {log_path}))>> nohup.out
```

the first part of the command line is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe).

After this, you only have to redirect (append) output to *nohup.out*.