# make nohup write other than nohup.out

Tags: bash, shell, nohup

I've been using below command to make tail to write nohup.out and also print the output on the terminal.

```
nohup train.py & tail -f nohup.out
```

However, I need nohup to use **different file names**.

When I try

```
nohup python train.py & tail -F vanila_v1.out
```

I'm getting following error message.

`tail: cannot open 'vanila_v1.out' for readingnohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out': No such file or directory`

I also tried 
`nohup python train.py & tail -F nohup.out > vanila_v1.txt`

Then it doesn't write an output on stdout.

How do I make nohup to write other than `nohup.out`?  I don't mind simultaneously writing two different files. But to keep track of different processes, I need the name to be different.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pipe the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` for the nohup command like:

```
$ nohup python train.py > vanila_v1.out 2>&1 & tail -F vanila_v1.out
```

At this point, the process will go into the background and you can use `tail -f vanila_v1.out`. That's one way to do it.

A little more information is available here for the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625224/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file). Here is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe) that uses the tee command rather that `>` to achieve the same in one go.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the comment but when I try your command, it doesn't print out on stdout.

Comment: The reason why I used tail was to print out on stdout.

Comment: @Aaron The full command line would be `nohup python train.py > vanila_v1.out 2>&1 & tail -F vanila_v1.out`. There's a critical point here that I think you're missing: the parts before and after the `&` are *completely independent commands* (with the first being run in the background). Thus, you do the redirects for the first command as part of the first command, and have the second (`tail`) command read from wherever the first got redirected to.