# Linux Pipe viewer, how to split the pipe

Tags: linux, tar, pv

I'm trying to extract large .tar file using pv.

```
pv large_file.tar.gz | tar -xcf /../MyFolder.
```

The pv command works like expected,showing the progress in the console.

I'm trying to split the stdout, to show the progress both in the console and save the same standout, to a file.

I tried doing so with tee, but couldn't make it work.

```
pv large_file.tar.gz | tee /tmp/strout.log | tar -xcf /../MyFolder
```

Any suggestions how can i display the progress to the console an in the same time save it to a file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure that your original command works, as there are several errors in the options given to tar.

Given that `../MyFolder` exists, your first command need to be

```sh
    pv large_file.tar.gz | tar -xz -C ../MyFolder
```

If you insert tee call between `pv` and `tar` calls, then the whole chain works.

```sh
    pv large_file.tar.gz | tee /tmp/strout.log | tar -xz -C ../MyFolder
```

However i'm not sure it does what you expect. If you pipe pv output to tee, tee will pipe it to tar, and dump the same contents as the original tar to /tmp/strout.log, resulting in your tar extracted to `../MyFolder` and copied to /tmp/strout.log.

**EDIT**
As suggested by @DownloadPizza, you can use process substitution (see [How do I write stderr to a file while using "tee" with a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe)). By using `-f` flag with pv, your command will become

```sh
    pv -f large_file.tar.gz 2> >(tee /tmp/strout.log) > >(tar -xz -C ../MyFolder)
```

and will produce expected output.

Comment: Thanks! The last combination worked perfectly! Appritiate it a lot!

Answer (score 2):

PV progress is sent to stderr, can you try this?:
`pv large_file.tar.gz > >(tar -xz -C ./MyFolder/) | echo` you might need to edit the tar command as i couldnt get yours to work for me

Comment: Thank you! Both your answers worked perfectly together!