# How to pipe stdout and stderr separately to two different processes while letting them appear in the terminal?

Tags: bash

I have a process that generates output both on `stderr` and `stdout`.

I need to pipe these two different commands, but I would also like to keep seeing them on the terminal.

So I tried something like this as a proof of concept:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

function generate_output() {
  echo This message goes to stderr 1>&2
  echo This message goes to stdout
}

generate_output \
    1> >(tee <&0 >(cat > out.log)) \
    2> >(tee <&0 >(cat > err.log))
```

`cat > out.log` is a dummy command that will be replaced by something else when I figure out how to make this work.

It almost works :

```
$ cat err.log 
This message goes to stderr
```

And I see the output on the terminal.

So far so good !

But :

```
$ cat out.log 
This message goes to stdout
This message goes to stderr
```

**Why does the "stderr" message ends up in out.log ?**

What puzzles me even more is that if I remove the tee command, the log file contain the expected result (but then I loose terminal output)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

function generate_output() {
  echo This message goes to stderr 1>&2
  echo This message goes to stdout
}

generate_output \
    1> >(cat > out.log) \
    2> >(cat > err.log)
```

Comment: this question already ansered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both `tee`s are writing to stdout. That's fine for the first one but a problem for the second one since when the `2>` redirection is processed `1>` has already redirected stdout. That means that the second `tee` isn't writing to the terminal, but to the first `tee` process. Oops!

An elegant way to fix it is to have each of the `tee`s write to the fd that they're reading from. Adding `>&2` to the second one will fix the problem.  And since I can tell you like parallel structure, you can add an explicit `>&1` to the first one as well.

This will have the nice effect of preserving the separation of stdout and stderr in case there are any downstream consumers of your script's output.

```
generate_output \
    1> >(tee <&0 >(cat > out.log) >&1) \
    2> >(tee <&0 >(cat > err.log) >&2)
```

You can then eliminate some redundancies:

- `<&0` redirects stdin into stdin, which does nothing.
- `>(cat >file)` is a complicated way of writing `file`. You can get the same effect just by passing `out.log` and `err.log` directly to `tee`.

```
generate_output \
    1> >(tee out.log >&1) \
    2> >(tee err.log >&2)
```

Answer (score 3):

The errors are going into `out.log` because `tee` is inheriting the redirected stdout. So when it writes to its stdout, it goes to the first `tee` process.

Change the order of your redirections to fix this:

```
generate_output \
    2> >(tee <&0 >(cat > err.log)) \
    1> >(tee <&0 >(cat > out.log))
```