# docker-compose build output to logfile

Tags: docker-compose, tee

What I want to archive:

> I want to store the output of the docker build process in a file and see it in the terminal online.

What I try is:

> docker-compose build --progress plain  myenv  | tee  myenv.log

What I get is:

> I see the output of the build process in the terminal.
> The file myenv.log is generated, but is empty (size 0 Byte).

What I use:

> Ubuntu 22.04 @ WSL version: 2.0.9.0 @ Windows 11

> docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown

Any Idea?

Comment: redirect stderr

Comment: Thank your @BenjaminGruenbaum.   Together with this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-standard-error-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe/14737103#14737103     i have found a working solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on feedback of @BenjaminGruenbaum and [How do I write standard error to a file while using "tee" with a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-standard-error-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe/14737103#14737103)
, my working solution now looks like:

```
{ { docker-compose build --no-cache --progress plain  myenv  | (tee   std.log);  } 2>&1 1>&3 | tee err.log; } 3>&1 1>&2
```

The file 'std.log' remains empty. The expected log is found in 'err.log'. It's a bit supprising that the docker-compose build output is classified as an error but that's what it is.

Comment: If you don't care about separating stdout/stderr, `docker-compose build ... 2>&1 | tee filename` would be shorter.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze  ! This is indeed the more elegant solution.  (Seems I should study more about bash pipes. )

Comment: stderr does not mean error confusingly