# Shell script - Output to both the terminal and a log file in a sub-shell

Tags: linux, shell, logging, terminal, subshell

I have a few shell scripts that are intended to work together. The first script (script1.sh) calls the next script in a sub-shell. The second script (script2.sh) needs to "return" something for the first script to use. I need the last line that is echoed in the second script. However, when I use it this way, any output via echo in the second script does not get output to the terminal. I want all output from the first and second (and third, and fourth, ...) to be output to the terminal, but also written to a log file.

script1.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

func_one() {
   RESULT=$(./script2.sh | tail -1)
   echo "RESULT: $RESULT"
}

func_one | tee log_file.log
```

script2.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello"
echo "World!"
```

Attempt 1 output:

```
$ ./script1.sh
RESULT: World!
$
```

log_file.log contents:

```
RESULT: World!
```

If I try to redirect output in the second script, then it outputs to the terminal, but not to the log file:

script2.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello" >&2
echo "World!" >&2
```

Attempt 2 output:

```
$ ./script1.sh
Hello
World!
RESULT:
```

log_file.log contents:

```
RESULT:
```

I also tried outputting to terminal and tee on the same line in script 1:

```
func_one >&2 | tee log_file.log
```

But that gives the same result as the first attempt.

What I would like is to have both output to the terminal AND written to the .log file: (if it was working correctly)

```
$ ./script1.sh
Hello
World!
RESULT: World!
$
```

log_file.log contents:

```
Hello
World!
RESULT: World!
```

How can I go about getting this result? Also, it would be preferred to NOT use bash, as a few of our machines we are going to be running this on do not have bash.

I've looked here:
[How do I get both STDOUT and STDERR to go to the terminal and a log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363223/how-do-i-get-both-stdout-and-stderr-to-go-to-the-terminal-and-a-log-file)
but that didn't help in my case.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the output of script2.sh sent to the terminal without interfering with the work of script1.sh, try this modification of script1.sh:

```
$ cat script1.sh
#!/bin/bash

func_one() {
   RESULT=$(./script2.sh | tee >(cat >&2) | tail -1)
   echo "RESULT: $RESULT"
}

func_one | tee log_file.log
```

Here, the first tee command makes sure that all `script2.sh` output appears, via stderr, on the terminal.  To do this, *process substitution* is needed (and this, in turn, requires an upgrade from `sh` to `bash`).

The output is:

```
$ ./script1.sh
Hello
World!
RESULT: World!
```

#### Variation

This is the same as the above except that we don't touch stderr (you may want to reserve that errors).  Here, we create an additional file descripter, `3`, to duplicate stdout:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3>&1
func_one() {
   RESULT=$(./script2.sh | tee >(cat >&3) | tail -1)
   echo "RESULT: $RESULT"
}

func_one | tee log_file.log
```